# Ruby on Rails -- Nested radio buttons issue (When one is selected other is deselected)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested, radio-button

So I have a form in which each question has different options and one of the options in each question needs to be selected:

```
<% @exam.exam_questions.each do |question|%>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="individual_question_container">
                                    <div class="header">
                                      <h3>Question: <%= question.question_no %> / <%= @exam.exam_questions.count %></h3>
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class="container_body">
                                      <br />
                                      <h4><%= question.question%></h4>
                                      <br />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="footer">
                                        <br />
                                        <% if question.question_type == 1%>
                                            <% if question.correct_answers.split(',').count == 1 %>
                                                <% question.options.split(',').each do |option| %>
                                                    <%= radio_button_tag :exam_answer_answer_mcq, option_position_to_answer(question.options.split(',').find_index(option)), false, :name => "exam_answers[][answer_mcq]"%> <!-- RADIO BUTTON TAG HERE -->
                                                    <label><%= option %></label>
                                                    <br />
                                                <% end %>
                                            <% else %>
                                                <% question.options.split(',').each do |option| %>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" name ="<%=question.id%>--<%=question.options.split(',').find_index(option)%>--name" value="<%=option_position_to_answer(question.options.split(',').find_index(option))%>" id="<%=question.id%>--<%=question.options.split(',').find_index(option)%>--id" onclick="add_to_textbox('<%=question.id%>--<%=question.options.split(',').find_index(option)%>--id','<%=question.id%>--mainTextBox')">
                                                    <label><%= option %></label>
                                                    <br />
                                                <% end %>
                                                <%= hidden_field_tag :exam_answer_answer_mcq, '', :name => "exam_answers[][answer_mcq]", id:"#{question.id}--mainTextBox"%>
                                            <% end %>
                                        <% elsif question.question_type == 2 %>
                                            <%= text_area_tag :exam_answer_answer_seq, '', :name => "exam_answers[][answer_seq]", :class => "form-control", :rows => 15, :placeholder => "Answer...."%>
                                        <% end %>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        <%= hidden_field_tag :exam_answer_exam_question_id, question.id, :name => "exam_answers[][exam_question_id]"%>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag :exam_answer_student_id, current_student.id, :name => "exam_answers[][student_id]"%>
                        <%= hidden_field_tag :exam_answer_exam_id, question.exam_id, :name => "exam_answers[][exam_id]"%>
                        <% end %>
```

Suppose I select an option from one question( radio button ), when I move on to the next question and select another option the option I selected from the previous question becomes unselected. Can anyone tell em how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is using the same name for each set of radio buttons (`exam_answers[][answer_mcq]`).

If you update your code to use [`each_with_index`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index) or the question's ID (or whatever you like really) and add this on to the `radio_button_tag` name, this will work for you.

For example:

```
<% @exam.exam_questions.each_with_index do |question, i|%>
  ...
  <%= radio_button_tag :exam_answer_answer_mcq, option_position_to_answer(question.options.split(',').find_index(option)), false, :name => "exam_answers[][answer_mcq_#{i}]"%>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Or:

```
<%= radio_button_tag "exam_answer_answer_mcq_#{i}", option_position_to_answer(question.options.split(',').find_index(option)), false, :name => "exam_answers[][answer_mcq_#{question.id}]"%>
```

Using the same name groups all the options together, meaning only one can be selected per group. Updating to use an approach as above will overcome this by differentiating the groups.

Hope that helps - let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense but then how do I pass on the parameters:

` params[:exam_questions].each do |exam_question_params|
                parameters = ActionController::Parameters.new(exam_question_params)
                exam_question = ExamQuestion.new(parameters.permit(:question, :correct_answers, :question_no, :options, :question_type, :exam_id))
                exam_question.save
            end `

Comment: I'd suggest a new question asking that - it's a little hard to make out in a comment :) Get the radio buttons working, then add a question showing the params as you want them and how they're currently coming in, and it'll be nice and clear to answer. That good? Feel free to '@' me in there if you like. Hope this helped here - if so and you think it resolves this specific issue, please tick the question to accept it as an answer.